# Why is my year reputation larger than my total reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

[My reputation for the year is more than my total rep](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/7/year/gaming/2014-01-01/69152#69152).

[image]

How is it possible that my year reputation is higher than my total reputation? This is my first year on this site so it's not possible that I lost points because of downvotes I received in previous years.

Comment: Did you lose 110 rep to downvotes the year before?

Comment: At a guess, the problem here is probably cacheing.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I wanted to ask this question on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation).
It's asking, 'Why is my total reputation less than my monthly reputation?'

The [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141691/259583) is likely the same as for my question.

> The discrepancy is by design:
>
> - **Total reputation** is your current reputation on the site (accurate to within 24 hours).
> - **Month reputation** is the amount by which your reputation changed that month, *excluding "private" reputation events*. Certain
>   reputation events are excluded from your public user profile, such as
>   deleted posts or downvotes, so those are excluded from the leagues as
>   well.
>
> In other words, "total reputation" includes private reputation events,
> while "month reputation" does not.

Now we only have to change 'Month' to 'Year' and my question is answered:)